# How to display an unordered list (UL) with list items (LI) within it in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to display an unordered list (UL) with list items (LI) within it.
I Have shared the code below that I have tried. PLease tell my mistake.
Your help must be appreciated.
Generates an error like
/src/index.js
Line 15:21:  'data' is not defined  no-undef
Line 16:11:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

```
DataList.js file:-

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'reactdom';
function DataList (props) {
<h2>code goes here</h2>
const data = props.data;
const listitems= data.map((data)=>
<li>{data}</li>
)
return(
<ul>
{listitems}
</ul>
)
}
const data = [
{ name: 'Daniel', age: 25 },
{ name: 'John', age: 24 },
{ name: 'Jen', age: 31 },
];


export default DataList;

 
index.js file:-

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import DataList from './DataList';


ReactDOM.render(
<div>
<App/>
<DataList data= {data.name}
data= {data.age}/>
</div>
,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You should paste the code into your question in a code block. Links to images will fail in time!

Comment: What have you tried  If you have tried some method then please provide with the errors that you got or some unwanted result. Please don't expect the community to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

> The first problem I notice is with index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DataList from './DataList';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>

    // You cannot use 'data' as a prop name twice !
    // And you're passing data that doesn't exist in index.js
    <DataList data={data.name} data={data.age}/>

  </div>
  ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> Here's a simple fix to index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DataList from './DataList';

// Create your 'data' in index.js, rather than DataList.js
const data = [
  { name: 'Daniel', age: 25 },
  { name: 'John', age: 24 },
  { name: 'Jen', age: 31 },
  ];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>

    // And pass the whole Array as a prop
    <DataList data={data} />

  </div>
  ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

> Now that is handled, let's take a look at DataList.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function DataList(props) {
  // I'm not sure what this h2 is, but it's not supposed to be here.
  <h2>code goes here</h2>

  // After we fixed the prop naming in index.js, this line is now fine
  const data = props.data;

  // This is the correct way to create an <li> for each object in our array.
  // But notice that the object is being used as a 'whole', you need it's properties
  const listitems = data.map((data) => <li>{data}</li>);

  return <ul>{listitems}</ul>;
}

export default DataList;
```

> Let's take care of that, shall we?

```
import React from 'react';

function DataList(props) {
  const data = props.data;

  // If you wish to render the names of each person object, do the following:
  const nameList = data.map((person) => <li>{person.name}</li>);

  // If you wish to render the age of each person object, do the following:
  const ageList = data.map((person) => <li>{person.age}</li>);

  // If you want both names, and age do as following:
  const personList = data.map((person) => (
    <li>{`Name: ${person.name}, Age: ${person.age}`}</li>
  ));

  // Don't forget to render the correct list!
  return <ul>{ nameList || ageList || personList }</ul>;
}

export default DataList;
```

Comment: Thanku vry much @ belferink 1996

Comment: hey belferink 1996 ....I have render the personList and the output shown in browser is like                                                                                                                             
Name: ${person.name}, Age: ${person.age}
Name: ${person.name}, Age: ${person.age}
Name: ${person.name}, Age: ${person.age}

Comment: That should not happen, I have misled you, sorry. Paste the following line as a fix: <li>Name: {person.name}, Age: {person.age}</li>